# How can I use SQL Server CE for my ASP.net MVC membership/authorization project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, sql-server-ce

I'm wondering if I can use SQL Server CE instead of SQL Server Express+ as my database for my membership? Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL CE with ASP.net Membership, Role and Profile provider.
Check this codeplex site for providers and config sample.

http://sqlcemembership.codeplex.com/

EDIT:
Microsoft supplied Universal Provider has been released.
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx

Comment: how do I use the Universal Provider?

Comment: I think the example in link is good enough. Install API with NuGet Extension Manager, add membership setting in web.config. I hope API usage could be similar as SQL Membership provider.

Comment: ok cool. sqlcemembership worked for me but i'm having trouble with the second one...

Comment: nevermind. Universal Provider worked like a charm! I think it's the same API too.. not too different.